# Swift generic type with Void cannot invoke method without argument

Tags: swift, generics

Assume I have a generic type like `class Foo <T>` with a method like `func bar (_ arg: T)`.

If I do `let foo = Foo<Void>()`, I cannot do `foo.bar()` without getting:

```
Cannot invoke 'bar' with no arguments
```

Didn't this used to work in older versions of Swift? Or am I doing something wrong?

`foo.bar(())` works, but is obviously less than ideal.

Comment: You could define a `func bar() { bar(()) }` overload in a `extension Foo where T == Void`, similar to [the example shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46863180/2976878).

Comment: I am not sure what is your question. The method has one argument of type `Void` and you have to specify it when invoking the method. What is your ideal?

Comment: @Hamish Your answer seems to be working. I'll accept it when you're ready.

Comment: @Sulthan `foo.bar()` is the ideal. `foo.bar(())` is 2 characters too many. It worked before in previous Swift versions.

Comment: @aleclarson I decided it would be best just to update my existing answer to note how it could be used to work with methods as well, so unless you have any objections, we can just close this as a dupe now.

Comment: @Hamish Sure thing, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the argument as optional and define nil as a default value to achieve this:

```
func bar (_ arg: T? = nil)
```

Comment: `Default argument value of type '()' cannot be converted to type 'T'`

Comment: Good answer, but it won't work for my use case. The function requires a non-nil value, except in the case of a `Void` generic type.