# How to use Result when success don’t have value?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a Result, success don't have value.

```
typealias MyResult = Result<Void, Error>
```

Use

```
let myResult: MyResult = .success(())
```

Is it possible like this?

```
let myResult: MyResult = .success()
```

I try to change define MyResult, but not correctly :(

```
typealias MyResult = Result<_, Error>   //Expected type
typealias MyResult = Result<nil, Error> //Expected type
```

Is there any other way to define this Result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46863180/1187415 for a workaround.

Answer (score -2):

Use `Error?` as your result type.

```swift
typealias MyResult = Error?

extension MyResult {

    var isSucceeded: Bool { return self == .none } 
}
```

Comment: The question is about the [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type of Swift 5