# Generics that can implement both Void and Codable

Tags: swift

Here I have a struct that I use for api results

```
struct Response<Result> {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let result: Result
}
```

Now normally getting this to conform to `Codable` would mean that the `Result` object needs to be `Codable`. Doing that would look like one of the following

```
struct Response<Result: Codable>: Codable {...}

// or

extension Response: Codable where Result: Codable {}
```

The problem I'm getting is that some responses don't have the `result` key and I want to be able to use the `Response` object like with the `Void` type instead `Response<Void>` much like this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837915/generic-swift-4-enum-with-void-associated-type).

Currently I have a possible way around this, to just declare another `Response` type with no `result` variable inside it like this:

```
struct BaseResponse {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
}
```

Is there a way around this so that I don't have to declare another `Response` type?

---

I've tried doing the following but nothing works

1. I can't conform `Void` to `Codable`
2. Have another extension conformance to codable where `Result: Void`

```
extension Response: Codable where Result: Codable {}

extension Response: Codable where Result: Void {}
```

3. `Never` also won't work because it doesn't have it's own initializer therefore I can't conform it to `Codable`
4. Create a `Nothing` type that conforms to `Codable` like this

```
struct Nothing: Codable, Hashable {
    init() {}

    static var nothing: Nothing { return .init() }
}
```

So I can use the response like this

```
let response: Response<Nothing> = Response(
    status: 200,
    message: "Success",
    result: .nothing
)

or

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.status = try container.decode(forKey: .status)
    self.message = try container.decode(forKey: .message)

    // These lines don't work.
    if let result = try container.decodeIfPresent(Result.self, forKey: .result) {
        self.result = result
    } else {
        self = .nothing
    }
}
```

But the thing is I can't have a `decodeIfPresent` method specific for the `Nothing` type. So much for that.

Comment: Just get rid of generic in `Response` and make `result` optional

Comment: But that would defeat the point of having `result` as a generic parameter, I might as well have made it into `result: Any?`

Comment: That would seem to do the trick. Are you sure you _need_ to use generics?

Comment: Yeah, so I wouldn't have to do null checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your `init(from:)` method like this:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
    message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)

    if Result.self is Nothing.Type {
        result = Nothing() as! Result
    } else {
        result = try container.decode(Result.self, forKey: .result)
    }
}
```

You detect that you're in the `Response<Nothing>` case and skip the decoding of the result altogether.  This way you keep your normal `result` decoding in the case where a result is required and can leave it non-optional.

Comment: I thought this would result to a crash, but it worked. I tried doing this using extensions `extension Response where Result: Nothing` and `extension Response` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Make `result` as `optional` type **`Result?`**. Now, when the *response* contains the value against `result` key, it will be set in the `result` property. Otherwise, it will remain `nil` if no `result` key is present.

```
struct Response<Result: Codable>: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String
    let result: Result? //here....
}
```

**Parse** the data like,

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<String>.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Use whatever type you want to in `Response<String>` as per your requirement.

**Example:**

1. If *JSON* is `{"status":1,"message":"This is a message","result":"QWERTY"}`

then `response` is, `Response<String>(status: 1, message: "This is a message", result: Optional("QWERTY"))`

2. If *JSON* is `{"status":1,"message":"This is a message"}`

then `response` is, `Response<String>(status: 1, message: "This is a message", result: nil))`

Comment: Yeah I get that, this was my initial implementation actually, but doing this would mean that I'd have to do null checks on the `result` which I don't want to do which is why I created another ResponseType with no `result` inside it.

Comment: But in .nothing also, you need to check for result type. In any case, when using the result, you need to check if there is any value in result or not.